# How did I enable atom feeds in a fresh WP3 install?

Tags: customization, widgets, feed

I've just install Wordpress 3, and I can't figure out how to put an atom link in the sidebar, under (or otherwise near) the RSS links.  I looked at sidebar.php, but it simply references a meta 'widget', and I can't figure out how to modify or configure this widget (or any widget for that matter).  Can somebody guide me as to how to enable atom feeds?

Comment: The title of this should be changed to "How can I link to the Atom feed for my site?". Atom doesn't need to be 'enabled', you just need to link to it. The answer by Sorich87 is correct and shows how to create a link to your Atom feed as well as how to modify the Meta widget specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wp_meta hook:

```
function extend_meta() {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_bloginfo('atom_url') . '" title="' . esc_attr( __( 'Syndicate this site using Atom' ) ) . '">' . __('Entries Atom Feed') . '</a></li>';
}

add_action( 'wp_meta', 'extend_meta' );
```

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know this was possible. Worthy of note is the get_bloginfo('atom_url') which gets the actual Atom url (and is the part Tristan most needed to know). To output the url directly (say in your sidebar.php file) you can use bloginfo('atom_url') without the 'get_' part.